# Encode Mesh from text-file

Tags: python, text, multidimensional-array, blender, mesh

I want to encode a 3D-Model with this text-syntax-structure to Blender:

```
<p>
c(255,84,22)
fs(-1)
p(-9,-8,27)
p(-9,-23,27)
p(-7,-24,63)
p(-7,-11,63)
</p>
```

What's relevant to create the mesh are these:

- *`<p>`* marks a face-container (like in HTMLs)
- *`c`* marks the color
- *`p`* marks the vertex coordinates (min. of 3 in each face-container)
- *`</p>`* marks the end of the face
- *`fs`*: ignore this

Obviously, the mesh contains a lot of these face containers, so it would be really a time waste to create this mesh manually.
I have written already a working Script, but this extracts only the coordinates and contains not faces.

Now I want to implement those faces, so I expanded the script, but it is not working:

```
faces = [] #Array, where all the vertex Indecies from curFace are stored
verts = [] #Array, where all the vertex coordinates from coords are stored
vertIndex = 0
with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
for line in file:
    if not line.startswith('<p>'):
        continue #Skip lines which don't contain a <p>
    if line.startswith('<p>'):
        curFace = []
        for container in line: #Do a loop while </p> is reached
            if container.startswith('p'):
                coords = container.strip('\np()/ ').split(',') #Remove certain characters and split line into 3 parts (XYZ) 
                coords = list(map(float, coords))
                verts.append(coords) #Send the vertex coordinates from the current face to verts[]
                curFace.append(vertIndex)
                vertIndex += 1
            elif container.startswith('</p>'):
                faces.append(curFace) #Send the vertex Indecies from the current face to faces[] 
                break #Stop the face-for-loop and return to main line-for-loop
            elif not container.startswith('p') or not container.startswith('</p>'):
                continue #Skip lines in the container which don't start with 'p' or '</p>'
mesh.from_pydata(verts,[],faces) #Create the entire mesh with the arrays
```

P.S.: This is only an extract of the main part.
The console shows no error. Could someone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your sample data matches your file then the basic logic of your loops are out.

The logic of your loops depends on all face data being on one line.

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        # the following is done for each line
        if not line.startswith('<p>'):
            # if the line doesn't start with <p> go to next line
            continue
        if line.startswith('<p>'):
            # if line starts with <p> do the following with 
            # the rest of the line
            curFace = []
            for face in line: # here your are still on the line with <p>
                if line.startswith('p'): # your still on the first line
                    # before this you need to get the next line from the file
                    coords = line.strip('\np()/ ').split(',')
```